# Display preview for psd file upload

Tags: php, jquery, preview, psd, uploadcare

I am integrating uploadcare to my php form where user can upload files of all types and see preview of uploads once upload complete. Right now my uploadcare is displaying preview image fr image file types like png, jpg. But I also need to show preview for PSD file types. How do I do that? For note, once the files are uploaded they are appended to dynamically created divs using jquery and the previews are displayed inside the dynamic div.

Comment: Not sure what you meant. Have a look at my jquery snippet that create the div and display preview in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kamela101/sLoqq18r/

Comment: php has no native support for `PSD` files ( presumably Photoshop PSD ) but you might be able to use `imagick` ~ http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: As you can see the uploader is using jquery to output the preview and to append so I am not sure how to use php in this case. Any help or guidance would be great

Comment: today, Uploadcare does not support PDF and PSD processing, so you'll have to generate previews via 3rd party services or software.